# How do I remove the index.php from all URLS in Craft 2 CMS?

Tags: templating, craft2

I am very new to Craft and have only been working with it for a few hours. However, I am stuck with something I can't seem to figure out.

I understand the basics of templates, of which I have an index.php using `% extends "_layout" %` Then I created a new Section with the Section Type set as Single for About. Craft sets the Entry template to about and I have the URL set to be about. Then I create a new template file called about.html.

However, the problem comes when I go to view it on localhost/about as I get the following message;

**The requested URL /about was not found on this server.**

But when I navigate to index.php/about it is there. I'm confused as to why the architecture of the URL is set up this way as on a normal website you would'nt have index.php/ before every other page on your site.

Is this fixable?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you haven't set up your .htaccess file or have failed to rename it. The file in the default set up doesn't have the `.` at the start.

Read https://docs.craftcms.com/v2/installing.html carefully. The bit concerning htaccess is just before step 2.

Also ensure you're files are in the right place.

Comment: My htaccess file is .htaccess and contains the text 'deny from all'

Comment: @Al-76 that's probably the wrong .htaccess file. You need to have a .htaccess in the public folder.

Comment: @AbbeyDesign Thank you very much for pointing that out. I have updated this one and the URLS are now correct.